# SQL Alchemy - BigQuery - Multiselect - Multijob result

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, sqlalchemy

Please find below minimum reproducible code to run a muti statement select. The problem here is, Big Query runs the select statement as multiple statements, and the result contains dataset from the the first dataset only, everything else is discarded.

You can run this in a Big Query console and see the difference.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery


def run_query(sql_query):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = client.query(sql_query)

    # Wait for the job to complete
    results = query_job.result()
    print("Query complete!")
    print(f"Results: {results.total_rows}")

    for row in results:
        print(row)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    sql_query = """
        BEGIN
            FOR record IN 
            (
            SELECT num FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 5)) AS num
            )
            DO
            WITH numbers AS (
                SELECT num
                FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100)) AS num  -- Adjust the range as needed
            )
            SELECT num
            FROM numbers
            LIMIT 10;
            END FOR;
        END
    """

    # Execute the demo query
    run_query(sql_query)
```

As per the documentation, the query is split into multiple script jobs and executed differently, so we need to take the results separately form each child job as shown below

```
client = bigquery.Client()
query_job = client.query(sql_query)

# Wait for the job to complete
results = query_job.result()
print("Query complete!")
print(f"Results: {results.total_rows}")

for row in results:
    print(row)

print("Parent Job ID: ", query_job.job_id)

all_statements = client.list_jobs(parent_job=query_job.job_id)

for child_job in all_statements:
    job: QueryJob = child_job
    print(f"{job.job_id}, {job.state}")
    results = query_job.result()
    print(f"Child job results: {results.total_rows}")

    for row in results:
        print(row)
```

Note: The query is just for demonstrative purpose of multi statement execution only and the correctness of its functionality is never intended.

Now the question is, I am using `python-bigquery-sqlalchemy` and select the data using a table model. How to get the result of child jobs using `python-bigquery-sqlalchemy` as part of the resultset for example when running `query_string` with above sql query?

```
results = db.query(MyOrmTable).from_statement(query_string).all()
```

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#multiple-result-sets) help?